# Symmetric billinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be non zero symmetric bilinear form on $\Bbb{R^3}$.

Suppose that there exists linear transformation $T_i:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$ ,$i=1,2$ such that $\forall a,b \in \Bbb{R}^3$ ,

$$f(a,b)=T_1(a)T_2(b)$$

Then

I) rank $f$=1

II)  dim$\{b\in\Bbb{R}^3 :f(a,b)=0 \forall a\in\Bbb{R}^3\}=2$

III) $f$ is positive semi-definite or negative semi -definite

IV) $\{a:f(a,a)=0\}$ is a linear subspace of dimension $2$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting tips. This is very difficult to read as it stands.

Comment: OP, I tried to make it more readable. Tell us if this is want you wanted.